# ABCpdf - dont understand what is needed to run the project

Tags: asp.net, abcpdf9

new job, ASP.NET project, no nuget.
Without running installation of ABCpdf, is it possible just to add DLLs to the project and use it?

What is the difference between ABCpdf.dll, ABCpdf-32.dll, ABCpdf-64.dll?
How the application knows which ones to use?

In references I see only ABCpdf.dll, but ABCpdf-32.dll and ABCpdf-64.dll couldnt even be referenced.

Please explain to me how this can be used if ABCpdf is not installed?

Comment: Add these Dll's directly into the bin folder as you can't add reference to them(as per my experience on Win Forms applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a reference to ABCpdf.dll. ABCpdf.dll will need ABCpdf-32.dll in the same folder, if your app is for x86, and it will need ABCpdf-64.dll if your app is for x64.
Some of the more "exotic" functionality may need other dll's as well.

Comment: If you need to add a license, you can do so from the code with InstallSystemLicense See http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xsettings/1-methods/installsystemlicense.htm

Comment: thank, when I add this ABCpdf using nuget in my personal solution, after compilation I could find all 3 ABC dlls in bin folder, but for company project they are not using nuget, and I dont know what needs to be done to have all 3 ABC dlls in bin folder after compilation. How come after using nuget I get them there anuways?

Comment: don't know. If you reference the dll's in your project, they should be added to your bin folder when you build.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in the dependencies between versions. For example if you're using version 7, you'll also need the following DLL's in your bin directory (but they are not .NET DLL's so you can't add a reference to them): -

- ABCpdfCE7.dll
- PrintHook32.dll (or PrintHook64 for the 64-bit version)

I don't know what the dependencies are for v9 but it's worth finding out. To be honest you're probably better off downloading the installer anyway, as you'll need it to enter the license key. The license isn't cheap but it's a pretty good product. You might also want to have a look at iTextSharp.

Comment: the company I joined already using this products, supplying licence key via config file. The problem is that instantiation of Doc object fails with message "unable to find ABCpdf-32.dll", when I am trying to run it on Win7 64 bit. And I am new to this component and dont know how to make it work, in references there is only ABCpdf.dll, and I dont see any of ABCpdf-32 or ABCpdf-64 dlls at all... (no need to say noone on that company has any idea about this component :)

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587755/unable-to-load-dll-abcpdf9-32-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-ex - it's possible you need to change each project's platform settings to x86-32 instead of 'any cpu'

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the newest websupergoo, ran the exe, remembered where the files were installed, and then added the new ABCpdf reference from the new files.  The only other thing I had to do was to rename the AddHtml() method to AddHTML().  Compiled and ran just fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please describe your answer more so easily understand by another person